# Object For Key Returning Null when objectforkey is there

Tags: ios, ios7, for-loop, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am running a for loop and it cannot find the objects for the keys. I tried putting in an if statement in to see if it would have any different result and it logs no

This is my DescriptionDictionary (The log of it)

```
{
    (
    "Apple's big event: Here's what to expect",
    "WeChat helps Apple rack up bonus points in China",
    "China Mobile Wants Apple's iPhone 6 to be a Blowout Success",
    "What Will Apple Announce On September 9th? Software and Hardware Predictions For The iPhone 6 Event",
    "Apple seeks old magic with new products",
    "Five ways Apple's iPhone 6, iWatch launches may transform its business model",
    "Apple's Plan To Kill PayPal Has Finally Become Clear (AAPL)",
    "Apple's mojo on the line at unveiling",
    "Will Apple",
    "Apple adds new Flyover Tours Before the Big Launch for iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite ",
    "Apple: watching for new directions",
    "Apple Looks to Fashion World for iWatch Rollout",
    "Apple website to live stream iPhone 6 launch event only for Apple devices",
    "Is Apple planning a catwalk show for its iPhone/iWatch event?"
) =     (
    "After months of anticipation, the tech industry event of 2014 is upon us: Apple's product launch day. The tech giant has said almost nothing publicly about what's in store Tuesday, but industry observers have some ideas. Apple (AAPL, Tech30) is widely ...",
    "BEIJING (Reuters) - Apple Inc has a lot for which to thank people like Deng. A Beijing-based quality analyst, she gave only her surname as she's embarrassed by how much money she spends playing mobile games on WeChat, a hugely popular messaging app ...",
    "Apple Store in Pudong Shanghai. Source: Apple. Earlier this week the world's largest mobile carrier, China Mobile (NYSE: CHL ) , launched a pre-order site for the new, not-yet-released Apple (NASDAQ: AAPL ) iPhones. It wasn't the first time the carrier has ...",
    "For fans and followers, journalists and analysts, to pop culture experts, celebrities, and late night chat show hosts, this Tuesday is going to be just like Christmas Day. While Apple has not said what will be announced at its September 9th event ...",
    "With its highly awaited product launch this week, Apple is aiming for a new ",
    "Apple is building a giant white cube outside of the Flint Center in Cupertino, CA. James Martin/CNET Apple's launch of the larger screen iPhone 6 and preview of iWatch or a similar wearable will aim to silence critics who contend the company's innovation ...",
    "Apple has been quietly putting together a plan to blow open the mobile-payments industry, making major deals with credit-card companies in a move that could threaten the dominance of PayPal and other mobile-payment companies. These deals could make Apple ...",
    "SAN FRANCISCO ",
    "Just this past week we released our tour of Motorola",
    "Apple knows they need to work on Maps. Improving their product started with faster turnarounds for updates and correcting errors and it continues with 3D flyover tours for more an more cities. A flyover tour will not make the Maps app more useful, but it ...",
    "San Francisco (AFP) - Apple's mystery unveiling on Tuesday is expected to be a watershed moment for the California giant -- and the entire tech industry. Here are key things to watch for: - Can Tim Cook step up? - Chief executive Tim Cook will seek to ...",
    "As intrigue builds around the mystery wearable product Apple is rumored to be launching next week, a new thread has been added to the story: high fashion. According to a new report, fashion journalists have been invited to Apple's Sept. 9 event, a move ...",
    "The Apple launch event is the most teased event for a while now, and this made the Apple to want every Apple users to watch the video by streaming the event on the Apple website. Apple wants each and everyone on this globe to watch the launch event of the ...",
    "There's a mysterious white building being built at the site of Apple's Tuesday event. Fashion bloggers have been invited. Ergo? Could there be a glorious catwalk lurking inside Apple's mystery cube? James Martin/CNET I took all my clothes to the dry ..."
);
}
```

**and this is my set of keys**

```
"Apple's big event: Here's what to expect",
"WeChat helps Apple rack up bonus points in China",
"What Will Apple Announce On September 9th? Software and Hardware Predictions For The iPhone 6 Event",
"Apple's Plan To Kill PayPal Has Finally Become Clear (AAPL)",
"China Mobile Wants Apple's iPhone 6 to be a Blowout Success",
"Apple's mojo on the line at unveiling",
"Five ways Apple's iPhone 6, iWatch launches may transform its business model",
"Apple seeks old magic with new products",
"Apple: watching for new directions",
"Apple Looks to Fashion World for iWatch Rollout",
"Will Apple",
"Apple adds new Flyover Tours Before the Big Launch for iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite ",
"Is Apple planning a catwalk show for its iPhone/iWatch event?",
"Apple Hires Australia"
```

When i run this for loop it always logs no

```
for(NSString *string in _titleArray) {
    if([_descriptionDict objectForKey:string]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

**edit**
knowing that the dictionary is how it is thanks to the first answer, the question continues. How do i turn that into a normal dictionary

************EDIT*************
it seems i am forming them correctly according to the answer this is how it is formed

```
    descForTitles = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:descriptions forKey:titleArr];

    NSLog(@"Description Dict:%@", descForTitles);
```

but i still end up with it logging the same way

Comment: Learn how to read an NSLog.  When you see the `{}` characters, that means a dictionary, while `()` means an array.  So it's quite clear that your dictionary above has a single entry consisting of a key that's an array of all your key phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your original dictionary is a mapping of one large array to another large array. Dictionaries should be set up like this

```
@{@"key": @"object",
  @"otherKey": @"otherObject"};
```

And it will log like this:

```
{
key = object;
otherKey = otherObject;
}
```

The parentheses give it away that you have a single array on each side of the mapping.

You have something more like this:

```
@{@[@"key", @"otherKey"]:
  @[@"object", @"otherObject"]};
```

which logs like this, which looks like what you have.

```
{
(
    key,
    otherKey
) =     (
    object,
    otherObject
);
}
```

If you are getting these data as arrays to begin with, you may consider using the `NSDictionary` class method `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: forKeys:]` which takes two arrays as its arguments and will properly build a dictionary associating one to the other.

Comment: Is there a way to separate the two, since i have the titles in an array already?

Comment: `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objectArray forKeys:keysArray]` will give you a well-formed NSDictionary.

Comment: @inVINCEable - You do not!!  From your [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728340/nsdictionary-not-forming-properly-from-2-arrays): `sourceDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sourceArr forKey:titleArr];`.  Do you see a difference?